# Exim append text to message body for certain attachment extensions

Tags: exim, server-configuration

I've already disabled email delivery to our servers if certain attachment extension found.
But some extension I just can't disable, because our customers are frequently using them, like .zip

How can I configure exim to just prepend some text into the message body if certain attachment extension found?

Answer (score 2):

Can you do that using `transport_filter` on your `smtp` `driver`

> http://www.exim.org/exim-html-3.20/doc/html/spec_14.html#SEC417

```
remote_smtp:
  driver = smtp
  transport_filter  = /bin/sh -c "/etc/exim/extras/footer.sh ${message_id}"
```

### Example:

```
[root@web ~]# /bin/cat << EOF > /etc/exim/extras/footer.sh
#!/bin/sh

BODY=`/usr/sbin/exim -Mvb $1`

if [[ $BODY == *".zip"* ]]; then
    /usr/bin/altermime --multipart-insert --force-into-b64 --disclaimer-html=/etc/exim/extras/has-zip.html --input=/tmp/altermime.$DATE --force-for-bad-html
else
    /usr/bin/altermime --multipart-insert --force-into-b64 --disclaimer-html=/etc/exim/extras/empty.html --input=/tmp/altermime.$DATE --force-for-bad-html
fi

/bin/cat /tmp/altermime.$DATE
/bin/rm /tmp/altermime.$DATE

exit
EOF
```

### File dependency.

```
[root@web ~]# /bin/cat << EOF > /etc/exim/extras/has-zip.html
This message contains .ZIP file.
EOF
```

### File dependency.

```
[root@web ~]# /bin/echo "" > /etc/exim/extras/empty.html
```